# Django Test form ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms, django-testing

In my application I've extended [UserCreationForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) in a RegisterForm and i'm trying to test if register form returns ValidationError if password1 is not equal to password2. In each test attempt i received `AssertionError: ValidationError not raised`.

```
class RegisterViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.bad_data = {
            'email': self.email,
            'password1': 'valid_password1',
            'password2': 'valid_password2'
        }

    def test_register_registers_invalid_data(self):
        form = RegisterForm(self.bad_data)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())

        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            form.full_clean()
```

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True})
```

Any clue why it's not passing the test?

Comment: What is `self.bad_data` ? I only see `self.data`

Comment: sorry, i edited :D

Comment: Could you also add your form ?

Comment: it's added, check it out

Comment: Your code looks ok. Please try to add a `clean_password2` in your `RegisterForm` class which does super().clean_password2() but that shouldn't be required...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is from calling `full_clean`, which does not actually reraise any validation errors - instead any errors raised by methods called by `full_clean` (which includes `_clean_fields -> UserCreationForm.clean_password2`) will be caught and added to the form's ErrorDict.
Note that any field that did not pass validation will not show up in `form.cleaned_data` either.

Comment: so basically i have to test the method to find if i receive any error, did i understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, calling `form.clean_password2()` should raise the error you want.